# /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, vercel

when I try to access my API uploaded on vercel server, I'm getting this error.

Did anyone have the same error?

When I run it locally, it works fine.

> 2021-02-15T19:38:59.218Z  0109b575-a2e7-478e-aefe-aa3335b5b6b8    ERROR   Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
> /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
> at onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
> at Interface. (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:183:68)
> at Interface.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at Interface.close (readline.js:424:8)
> at Socket.onend (readline.js:202:10)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

code

```
import puppeteer, { Page } from 'puppeteer-core'
import chrome from 'chrome-aws-lambda'

export async function getOptions() {
  const isDev = !process.env.AWS_REGION
  let options;

  const chromeExecPaths = {
    win32: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    linux: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
    darwin: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
  }
  
  const exePath = chromeExecPaths[process.platform]

  if (isDev) {
    options = {
      args: [],
      executablePath: exePath,
      headless: true
    }
  } else {
    options = {
      args: chrome.args,
      executablePath: await chrome.executablePath,
      headless: chrome.headless
    }
  }

  return options
}

let _page: Page | null
async function getPage(): Promise<Page> {
  if (_page) {
    return _page
  }

  const options = await getOptions()
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options)

  _page = await browser.newPage()

  return _page
}


export async function getScreenshot(html: string, { width, height } = { width: 800, height: 800 }) {
  const page = await getPage();

  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.setViewport({ width, height });

  const file = await page.screenshot({ type: 'png' });

  return file;
}
```

Comment: I am using Node 18 in AWS and still get this error...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I had the same issue where puppeteer was running okay on my local environment but when i deployed to AWS EC2 i face up the same error **shared loading libraries**
**Solution**

1. First check the version of nodejs you are running and if its not **less than v14.0 or greater than v14.0**. Upgrade or downgrade (*recommended to upgrade*) and restart your app then try.

> The most common cause is a bug in Node.js v14.0.0 which broke extract-zip, the module Puppeteer uses to extract browser downloads into the right place. The bug was fixed in Node.js v14.1.0, so please make sure you're running that version or higher. Alternatively, if you cannot upgrade, you could downgrade to Node.js v12, but we recommend upgrading when possible.

2. *Trivial:-* Make sure the directory where your project folder is located is not owned by root.

For those who might have experience this issue while running on windows enviroment, You can try to pass **ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']** option when launching it chromium from code i.e

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']})
```

This will deactivate default behaviour of puppeteer from disabling any extensions usually used by chromium/chrome.

**Linux and MAcOS uses**

The issues that results in this error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
> error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory TROUBLESHOOTING

is mostly but not all the times caused by missing dependencies that are required in the latest version. The good thing is you can easily check the missing chrome dependencies causing the crash.

- Make sure you are in the root folder of your project
- Navigate to node_modules folder
- Navigate to the folder where puppeteer chrome Linux tools are installed

> - cd /project_folder/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/*linux-**some number***/chrome-linux
>   **replace the *linux-some number* with whatever ls will output**
> - ls  at /.local-chromium to check name of your directory

- At the last directory **[ chrome-linux ]** run below command to check the missing dependencies

  ldd chrome | grep not

if you see any missing dependencies, run this command to install everything and restart your application.

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils
```

Voila!! everything should be fixed

Comment: I had this issue in my AWS Lambda using Node 16.x. Works fine in Node 14, so downgraded back to Node 14.x until I have a pressing reason for upgrade :(

Comment: @Chris The pressing reason has arrived: AWS ended support for Node 14.x.

Comment: Since AWS deprecated Node14.x you can follow the solution of @Ali and use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214552/tmp-chromium-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libnss3-so-cannot-open-sha#answer-77037818 and use sparticuz/chromium: https://github.com/sparticuz/chromium

Answer (score 35):

Thanks to @andrew-mititi and his [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67117619/3211932), I was able to solve the issue in my environment, which is **Docker** **FROM node:16** (which is Debian GNU/Linux 10) + **puppeteer v13** (not puppeteer-core). I did the following steps:

- build & run Docker container: `make build & docker run`
- go to container: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash`
- find pptr chromium folder: `ls project_folder/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium`, it was `linux-961656` in my case
- find next folder: `ls project_folder/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-961656`, it was `chrome-linux`
- run missing-dependencies script in that folder: `ldd node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-961656/chrome-linux/chrome | grep not`, it should show something like

```sh
    libnss3.so => not found
    libnssutil3.so => not found
    libsmime3.so => not found
    libnspr4.so => not found
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libcups.so.2 => not found
    libdrm.so.2 => not found
    libdbus-1.so.3 => not found
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => not found
    libXcomposite.so.1 => not found
    libXdamage.so.1 => not found
    libXfixes.so.3 => not found
    libXrandr.so.2 => not found
    libgbm.so.1 => not found
    libasound.so.2 => not found
    libatspi.so.0 => not found
```

The last step was to convert this list into correct apt-get command and add it to the Docker make-script after installing the project's npm dependencies. In my case it was:

```sh
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libnss3 libnspr4 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcups2 libdrm2 libxkbcommon0 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxrandr2 libgbm1 libasound2
```

Comment: adding to the list - libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0

Comment: After a few hours of searching this was the only solution that worked for me. In addition I had to add the parameter " args: ["--no-sandbox"] " to the puppeteer.launch()

Comment: i changed my directory configuration https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer#configuration so the install directory for chrome was found under [install directory]/chrome/linux-*/chrome-linux64/

Answer (score 15):

For people who are actually using Vercel and not AWS:

The problem correctly lies in the Node.js version of your app. You must use Node.js 14 instead of 16 like all other answers mentioned. To do this on Vercel, do 2 things:

1. Go to your project's Settings page, in the General tab, Node.js Version section: Select `14.x`

[image: Config Node.js 14]

2. Inside your app's `package.json`, under `engines`, set `"node": "^14"`

```json
// package.json

{
  ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14"
  }
  ...
}
```

Reference: [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/how-do-i-return-an-error/node-js-version)

Comment: Thanks! I think this worked for me (since now I'm getting a different error: `2022-06-16T21:36:30.362Z 73c41748-464f-4512-b04c-4d3cdedf03d1 ERROR getPropertyDetails failed {
  error: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of undefined` even though the app works perfectly locally). At least Puppeteer now seems to install and run on Vercel!

Comment: node 14 doesn't work for me, still having the same issue

Comment: In my Vercel project's settings I have set node to version 18, though I still encountered the error. Adding `engines` option to `package.json` however did resolve an issue for me!! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

For anyone having `libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file` issue on aws lambda. For me the fix was to bump both `chrome-aws-lambda` and `puppeteer-core` to version >= 6.0.0 - this is minimum version required while running `runtime: nodejs14.x`.

Comment: After bumping up the version to >= 6.0.0, were you able to run it on Lambda ?
Doesn't the zip file exceed the lambda size limit ?

Comment: Same problem as @Ibra : the zip file is now heavier than 50mb, the limit. Any workaround ?

Comment: @ThibaultHenry
My workaround was to switch to a container image deployment.
Lambda allows up to 10GB docker images.

Answer (score 7):

The [chrome-aws-lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) project seems to be abandoned as of Sep 2023; the last commit was 2 years ago.

The [sparticuz/chromium](https://github.com/sparticuz/chromium) is a fork of `chrome-aws-lambda`, and it is well-maintained at the time of writing. There are minor differences in the API, but porting my old code to `sparticuz/chromium` was quick and easy.

I was able to get everything up and running on AWS Lambda with Node.js 18 on the first attempt; all went smoothly. Consider putting `sparticuz/chromium` into a Lambda layer to avoid the 50MB limit of Lambda.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding [jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) buildpack. Adding this buildpack worked for me.

```sh
heroku buildpacks:add jontewks/puppeteer
```

Also don't forget to trigger build with a commit.

Comment: Worked for me as of Dec 2021

Comment: damn this destroyed my nodejs app - new commits are not possible anymore: ´´´Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used´´´

Answer (score 4):

I didn't notice that my `serverless.yml` was on runtime: `nodejs16.x`. When I changed it to `nodejs14.x` I was able to run without this error on AWS Lambda.

#### Error

> "/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

#### Fix

Changed `serverless.yml` to

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
```

and redeployed

Comment: node 14 doesn't work for me, still having the same issue

Comment: Using AWS Lambda with node version 14.x it's working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue while working with linux server, you should install missing dependancies by using below command and restart your nodejs server.

```
apt-get install ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils
```

Comment: worked for Debian 10/11/12

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue while deploying my project's Docker image to AWS Lambda. Everything was working fine initially, but it suddenly stopped working and threw a libnss3.so error. Strangely, the code was working fine without the Docker container.

After investigating, I discovered that Docker now defaults to using Node.js version 20 when not explicitly defined in the Dockerfile.

**Before:**

`FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs`

**Fix:**

`FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:18`

This fix explicitly specifies Node.js version 18 in the Dockerfile, resolving the issue. If you're facing a similar problem, this adjustment might save you some troubleshooting time.