# Failed to launch the browser process!\n/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so Vercel

Tags: api, next.js, puppeteer, chromium, vercel

When I try to run Next js API on production Vercel I get this error

> Failed to launch the browser process!\n/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: [https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md%5Cn%22)

Locally everything works, but on production, I am having this error.

This is my code from API:

```
import chromium from "chrome-aws-lambda";

async function getBrowserInstance() {
  const executablePath = await chromium.executablePath;

  if (!executablePath) {
    // running locally
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    return puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      headless: true,
      defaultViewport: {
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
      },
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
    });
  }

  return chromium.puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      ...chromium.args,
      "--hide-scrollbars",
      "--disable-web-security",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    ],
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1280,
      height: 720,
    },
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
    headless: chromium.headless,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214552/tmp-chromium-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libnss3-so-cannot-open-sha)?