# Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, alpine-linux

I am trying to use puppeteer with node.js which is working fine on my local Mac OS but When the code goes through CI pipeline it throws following error

```
error: Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT
  
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

I have tried Troubleshooting docs but the given solutions are not working in my case

```
* docker - 
       ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser" \
        PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"
    RUN set -x \
        && apk update \
        && apk upgrade \
        && apk add --no-cache \
        udev \
        ttf-freefont \
        chromium \
        && npm install puppeteer



  *Node-
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
      ]
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was trying to run the node container in docker.

My environment is using:

- Docker version 20.10.12
- Ubuntu Version 20.04
- Puppeteer Version ^13.5.2 (not puppeteer-core)
- Node Version 16.16.0

You can run `ldd chrome | grep not` on a Linux machine to check which dependencies are missing.

> Go inside the running docker container - `docker exec -it [CONTAINER ID] /bin/bash`.
> Run the above command inside this path to find missing dependencies -
> **/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-[970485]/chrome-linux**

For more detailed steps, you can follow this [well explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71128432/10179841). Thanks to @dhilt for this answer.

*Add the missing dependencies in the docker file.*

Dockerfile (I didn't need to install chrome or chromium-browser)

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -f install -y --no-install-recommends \
        fonts-liberation \
        libgtk-3-0 \
        libwayland-client0 \
        xdg-utils \
        libu2f-udev \
        libvulkan1 \
        libnss3 \
        libnspr4 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libcups2 \
        libdrm2 \
        libxkbcommon0 \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libxfixes3 \
        libxrandr2 \
        libgbm1 \
        libasound2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

nodefile.js (The bowser is not installed locally so no need to set executablePath)

```
// linux
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['-no-sandbox']
    });
```

Please mark the response as answered if it is helpful, so that its helpful for other community members.